# Is there a simple way in linux to strip a website of text from command line?

Tags: html, linux, bash, parsing

I've been searching for a command line tool that would turn html code into just the text that would appear on the site... so it would be equivalent to in a web browser selecting everything and then pasting it into a text editor...

Anyone know of something in Ubuntu that would do this?  I'm trying to write a script to parse some webpages,  but would prefer not to have to deal with the HTML and would prefer to just parse the text that appears on the website.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
lynx -dump http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 7):

if you already have the html file:

```
lynx -dump file.html > file.txt
```

otherwise use @Ignacio's

Answer (score 3):

i think you need lynx:

```
lynx -dump http://stackoverflow.com > file
```